# How to prevent auto post back after alert() Ok click

Tags: jquery

How to prevent auto post back on click of alert message popup. Using jQuery I tried `return false;`. Can anyone help me - what is my mistake?

Here I am validating popup text box field:

```
function validatepopup() {
    var isValid = true;

    $('#txtUserIDAU,#txtUserNameAU,#txtPasswordAU,#txtConfimPasswordAU').each(function () {
                if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                    isValid = false;
                    $(this).css({
                        "border": "1px solid red",
                        "background": "#FFCECE"
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css({
                        "border": "",
                        "background": ""
                    });
                }
            });

    if (isValid == false) {
        alert('Please Enter Required Information !');

        return false;
    }
    else {
        SaveRecord();
        return true;
    }
}
```

AJAX function : I have created a new function for saving popup details but on click of alert message Page is posting back so my modal popup hide at time of post back

```
function SaveRecord() {
    if (checkListBox.GetSelectedValues().length != 0) {
        var PlantCode = {};
        PlantCode = checkListBox.GetSelectedItems();
        var ArrArr = $.map(PlantCode, function (n, i) {
            return [n.value];
        });

        var params = {
                    'UserID': $('#txtUserIDAU').val(), 'UserName': $('#txtUserNameAU').val(),
                    'Password': $('#txtPasswordAU').val(), 'Status': $('input[name="rdnStatus"]:checked').val(),
                    'CreatedBy': $('#txtUserIDAU').val(),
                    'LocationCode': ArrArr
        };

        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(params),
                    url: 'MobileUser_Login.aspx/SaveRecord',
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (!data.error) {
                            alert('Saved successfully !!');
                        }
                        else {
                            alert(data.error);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('Please select atlist one Plant'); //here post back happening
                ev.preventDefault();
                return false;
    }
}
```

Button Click Event:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
     OnClientClick="return validatepopup();" Text="Save" CssClass="buttonsuccess" />
```

Comment: in this function `SaveRecord()` **if** part is not returning anything? also you are not using the return value from the same function.

Comment: @शेखर You mean `alert('Saved Successfully !!');` message i need to to `return false` ryt ?

Comment: no like else statement where you are returning false. before the end of `if` `}` you are not returning anything?

Comment: @शेखर you mean I need to add `return true;` after if condition completed. ryt bro ?

Comment: @शेखर can you please modify my code as you suggested Please

Comment: in if block what do you want a postback?

Comment: No don't want any post back at any event I am not using any server side code So i want to prevent Post back event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your `function validatepopup() {` as below

```
else 
{
    SaveRecord();
    return true;
}
```

to

```
else 
{
    SaveRecord();
    return false;
}
```

### Edit 1

As you are returning values form the function `SaveRecord();` so use that return value like below

```
else
{
   return SaveRecord();
 }
```

Comment: Sekhar I tried as you suggested but again page is posting back

Comment: for time being can you comment `SaveRecord();` and then check?

Comment: In my code `Validatepopup()` is working as expected  only problem i am facing on `SaveRecord()` function i mean `alert('Please select atlist one Plant');` on this alert i ma getting Post Back Bro

Comment: OK sekhar i am commenting `SaveRecord()` if i am commenting `saverecord()` function not post back but also not saving part its obvious it means `validatepopup()` working perfectly

Comment: I tried returning `else
{
   return SaveRecord();
 }`  But again post back happening

Comment: do you have some error on console. can you check your browser console?

Comment: Yes i was getting error on `ev.preventDefault();` i just remove this line and now its not post backing Thanks Sekhar Bhai...

Comment: @ak74 happy to help :)